# powershell Get-ADComputer splits computername unintended

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i am writing a powershell script which should give me the pc names of my domain. this works too, but i have a pc name which is 50 characters long. without me wanting or intending it in any way, it splits my string. Unfortunately the name i write in an excel/csv file is splitted, so the actual pc name appears on two columns, which i don't intend. for all other pcs in the domain the code works.

my code looks like this

```
$username=$env:UserName

#foldertosave
$csvPath= "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\test.csv"

#subdomains
$subdomains="test","test2","test3","test4"

#counter for pcs
$count=0;

#array to save pclist

#pclist from subdomains 
$subdomainPcs = @();

#pclist from domain
$Computers =@();

#created object list for pc attributes
$pcsToList = @();

#get pcs from domain 
foreach($subdomain in $subdomains){
    $subdomainPcs += Get-ADComputer -Filter * -properties Name, operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion, LastLogonDate ,  DNSHostName, enabled  -SearchBase "DC=$subdomain , DC=test , DC=lan" -Server "$subdomain.test.lan" 
    $subdomainPcs.name
}
```

this code outputs the pc names of my domain and its subdomains.

Example outputs are:

`TEST1254`

`test45454`

`.....`

now i have a pc name that looks like this:

`TES3500-1CNF:3dd7d213-fa2d-469d-834c-71df6f4d0dasd`

i think the scheme is clear, anyway this is a string without separation.
what i get as output unfortunately is:

`TES3500-1`

`CNF:3dd7d213-fa2d-469d-834c-71df6f4d0dasd`

it somehow splits the pc name. I guess because it is too long. the exact pc name in my domain is 50 characters long.

Comment: Can you add all code, you're not showing how you're exporting this to a file.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon its already wrong after the foreach loop but i added the code wrote before

Comment: im confused, when you say the name is split, do you mean it doesnt fit in one console line so it wraps onto the next line ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon no it splits the computername in two names, i dont understand why beacuase i dont use a split operation. when i write the pc name in the csv, the computername is splitted

Comment: Can you try finding that specific computer having the `CNF` and try this: `$comp = Get-ADComputer theCNFComputer; $comp.Name -replace '\r?\n'` and see if that fixes the name (should be all in one line)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks for your help. it didn't solve the problem, but i can't even find the document, as long as i enter the username of the ad, in the active directory. under the pc-name there is also another value inside, which should be inside. something would be created completely wrong then

Comment: you should note that `CNF` objects are what's called a "conflict object" in Active Directory. It might be possible that this was a replication issue and the object is no longer there. you can read more about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/101494/all-about-active-directory-cnf-object-finding-vali

Comment: It's not a linebreak. There's a NULL byte in the name right before CNF.

Comment: Better rename that computer to stop it working against you in every way. See [Naming conventions in Active Directory for computers, domains, sites, and OUs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/naming-conventions-for-computer-domain-site-ou)